# Trying plasma changes all the Ubuntu desktop decorations?

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments

I tried plamsa (mistakenly thinking I met get a file picker that shows thumbnails - I didn't)... so I switch back to the Ubuntu 20 desktop (as selected from the login screen - now the window decorations and mouse cursor are all different?  Surely the window managers are sandboxed from each other?  Is there away to undo this?

Thanks,

Simon

Oh and if anyone knows of any file picker (NOT the file chooser - the picker which is launched in e.g. Firefox when you select a file to upload) on any linux desktop that shows image thumbnails, please let me know!

Comment: "*now the window decorations and mouse cursor are all different? Surely the window managers are sandboxed from each other? Is there away to undo this?*" - No. At least no, not easily. You made a mistake thinking you could change the DE and easily change back. A desktop environment contains dozens of packages and it can be extremely messy to change a DE on an installed system. This is why distros come with a particular DE and why Ubuntu comes in so many official [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). In the future if you want to try a DE, use a live session.

Comment: The great gift of open software is being able to see all the whirling gears and cogs of the operating system and the desktop stack, and you can change the gears and cogs to do something different. The great curse is that you need to get the fittings just right when you do make changes, or a flying bit will smack you in the face.

Comment: Ubuntu has used the *year* format for releases for *snap* only products since 2016; eg. Ubuntu Core 16 etc. KDE is packaged only for *deb* based products (all community desktops are) so won't run on a 20 system, only 20.04 which is *deb* based.  20 is not 20.04 so please correct your question (it implies a different product intended for *headless* operation only; with only GNOME and specific apps available for it which were packaged as snap)